# How to write an if-else condition inside a HTML button tag?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using title attribute in button to show a tool  tip on the button. I want to change the tool tip according to the changes of the button color.(Button color is changed by keeping a variable value changed inside the button click) I have used the following method . But it didn't work. I am using angular js. How can I solve this?

```
<button type="button"  ng-click="vm.sortBy()"  class="btn change-
    button-color-{{vm.isColorChanged}} btn-circle btn-xs " 
    title="({{vm.isColorChanged}}==1) ? Test 1: Test 2"
                                data-toggle="modal">

  <strong >Sort</strong>-->
</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the expression like this.

```
title="{{ vm.isColorChanged == 1 ? 'Test 1': 'Test 2'}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-attr-title="{{ vm.isColorChanged == 1 ? 'Test 1': 'Test 2'}}"`. `ng-attr-title` will set dynamic attribute.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var _self = this;
    _self.isColorChanged = 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">

    <button type="button" ng-click="vm.sortByCutoffs()" 
            class="btn change-button-color-{{vm.isColorChanged}} btn-circle btn-xs " 
            ng-attr-title="{{ vm.isColorChanged == 1 ? 'Test 1': 'Test 2'}}"
            data-toggle="modal">

        <strong>Sort</strong>
    </button>
</div>
```